# C# WPF: The Resource Dictionary does not load at run time, but displays correctly in the designer

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, wpf-controls, resourcedictionary

**Problem:** The resource dictionary does not load at run time, but displays correctly in the designer. If I change the color in Dark.xaml to green, I can notice in the designer that my Window background (Layout.xaml) turns green. but when I compile the project in Debug mode, the background is just transparent !!

**What I have tried in App.xaml:**

```
<Applicationxmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflow" x:Class="StackOverflow.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="#"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**And:**

```
<Applicationxmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflow" x:Class="StackOverflow.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="#"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**In the source value, I tried these 3 possibilities:**

1. Theme/Dark.xaml
2. /StackOverflow;component/Theme/Dark.xaml
3. pack://application:,,,/StackOverflow;component/Theme/Dark.xaml

**App.xaml.cs:**

```
Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;

Window Window = Server.Status() is StatusCode.OK ? new Layout() : new Login();
Window.ShowDialog();

Current.Shutdown();
```

**Dark.xaml:**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Class="StackOverflow.Theme.Dark" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflow.Theme">
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Layout.Background">Red</SolidColorBrush>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Dark.xaml:** File Properties

- **Build Action:** Page
- **Copy to Output Directory:** Do not copy
- **Custom Tool:** XamlIntelliSenseFileGenerator
- **Custom Tool Namespace:**

**Dark.cs:**

```
namespace StackOverflow.Theme {
    public partial class Dark : ResourceDictionary {
        public Dark(){
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**Dark.cs:** File Properties

- **Build Action:** Compile
- **Copy to Output Directory:** Do not copy
- **Custom Tool:**
- **Custom Tool Namespace:**

**Note:** These two files (Dark.xaml / Dark.cs) are nested using the **File Nesting** extension ([Keith Wilson](https://youtu.be/ProEZxyO4hQ?t=120)).

**Layout.xaml:**

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflow.XAML"
    x:Class="StackOverflow.XAML.Layout"
    Background="{DynamicResource Layout.Background}"
    AllowsTransparency="True"/>
```

**Project File Structure:**

```
XAML
  Layout.xaml
Theme
  Dark.xaml
App.xaml
```

**Other information:**

> Solution Configuration: Debug
>
> Solution Platform: x64
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 v16.7.3

**Update:**

For some reason the problem reappeared with the Application StartUpUri, if you noticed that I didn't use this attribute because I have to verify the user's login before giving them access to the main window. So behind the code in App.xaml.cs I call Login.ShowDialog() and Layout.ShowDialog(). After setting this attribute to Layout Window, I can notice that the application is consuming the resources defined under Dark.cs, so if I change this line:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Layout.Background">​​Lime</SolidColorBrush>
```

The layout background changed **at runtime** to the color **Lime**, but I'm wondering if it is possible to use the same resources defined in App.xaml in all project windows, in my case StartUpUri will be Login.xaml, and under Login if the user info is correct I can prevent this window from showing and show my layout window. but the question here is whether this resource named "Layout.Background" can be used in both windows?

I got the idea that the app resource dictionary defined in App.xaml is like a super global resource, which I can use whenever I want. Is it correct? because this result does not seem to support it.

Comment: Please post the code in your `App.xaml.cs`.

Comment: I've updated the code, see above please.

Comment: The sample code is far from complete. What method are you overriding in `App.xaml.cs` and how exactly?

Comment: @ynsbl.eng Is there any update for your issue? Could you provide some details about Server.Status and StatusCode?